# sphinx search query text + float

Tags: php, search, sphinx, floating

I am struggling with getting sphinx search to work for my query:

```
((@city "^Amsterdam" | @regio "^Amsterdam$")  | (floatrange=lat,10,12))
```

It works fine when I filter results using php API:

```
$s->SetFilterFloatRange('lat', 10, 12)
```

but the problem is I need to have OR condition. My source looks like this

```
sql_field_string = title
sql_field_string = city
sql_field_string = regio
sql_attr_float = lat
sql_attr_float = lng
```

If I try to

```
  # search floatrange=lat,10,12
```

I also get 0 results...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is not good variant, but must working

$s->addSelect("if (in(city ,'Amsterdam') or in(region, 'Amsterdam') or (lat >= 10 and lat <= 12), 1, 0) foo");

$s->addFilter("foo", 1);

I still try to find a more elegant solution